# Can i filter folders to show on different views

Tags: list-view, filter, folder

How can i make it so that certain folders appear on different views?

ex:

View 1 (Folder A, Document A1, Document A2, Document A3)
View 2 (Folder B, Document B1, Document B2, Document B3)
View 3 (Folder A, Document A1, Document B3)

I know how to filter the documents, I just cannot figure out how to filter the folders... so it works the same as filtering the files.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use content type inheritance to accomplish this.  Create content types whose parent is "folder".  Name them "folderA", "folderB", or whatever makes sense in your environment.  Then you can filter those views on those content types.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Sharepoint Server 2010, you might also be able to accomplish this with File Sets. File Sets are folder-like in some ways, but they can also have their own metadata attributes just like files. Therefore by assigning a "filter group" metadata column to your File Serts you would in theory be able to filter them based on that value.

I can't say i've tried this yet myself but it's worth testing.